# jquery datatables row mouseover menu

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Question:** How would I add a mouseover menu for each row when using JQuery Datatables?
I tried using fnRowCallback, but I am not having much luck.

It would look similar to:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4NF/2/

Answer (score 1):

within the fnRowCallBack add a class to each of the elements requiring mouseover, and then call hover for each of those elements..

sample,

```
count=0;
$("#requestsTable").dataTable({
        "bFilter" :false,
        "bAutoWidth" :false,
        "aaData" : requestData,//whatever data u want to populate the table with
        "fnRowCallback" : processRow
});


function processRow(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
     if(count==1){ //hide every other row, link row
        count=0;
        $(nRow).addClass("hidden");
        return nRow;
     }
     count=1;
     //add hover functions for normal rows
    $(nRow).hover(function(){
         $( this ).next().show();
    },function(){
               $( this ).next().hide();
        });

    return nRow;
}
```

add style for the class hidden

```
.hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a basic example of how this would work in the fnRowCallBack function?  The trouble I am having is modifying the row to include the menu.

Comment: thanks for the example, but its not exactly what I am trying to achieve.  the basic table defined here http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4NF/9/ is what I am trying to accomplish - the links would only be displayed when the user mouses over the associated row. is this possible with datatables?

Comment: let me get this straight.. you will add a row of links below every row. The row of links needs to be visible only when you mouse over the normal row right?

Comment: if i am using sAjaxSource, how do I add the additional row?

Comment: same way, though if link row is always static with the same data, you need to return that row from the ajax source..
you can add the link row inside the `processRow` function to every row passed to it..